# codeigniter LEFT JOIN array issue

Tags: codeigniter

Can someone tell me how to write this properly?

```
    function get_tech() {

    $this->db->select('u.id
                      ,u.first_name
                      ,us.id
                      ,us.group_id');
    $this->db->from('users u');
    $this->db->join('users_groups us','us.id = u.id','left');
    $records = $this->db->where('us.group_id', '3');
    $data=array();
        foreach($records->result() as $row)
        {
        $data[$row->id] = $row->first_name;
        }
    return ($data);
}
```

I'm trying to populate a drop down menu using an array, but i need to only grab users that are part of  users_group/group_id = 3

therefore in my very limited knowledge I'm needing:

```
select X from Users LEFT JOIN users_groups WHERE group_ID = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$this->db->get()` in order to actually run your query.

```
function get_tech() {
    $this->db->select('u.id
                      ,u.first_name
                      ,us.id
                      ,us.group_id');
    $this->db->from('users u');
    $this->db->join('users_groups us','us.id = u.id','left');
    $this->db->where('us.group_id', '3');
    $records = $this->db->get();

    $data = array();
    foreach($records->result() as $row){
        $data[$row->id] = $row->first_name;
    }
    return $data;
}
```